# How to properly write the constraint code

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

I would like to set a UITextView inside `UITableViewCell`.
In some methods of the TableView function I wrote the code below,
however it causes the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors 
>    and
>    because they
>   have no common ancestor. Does the constraint or its anchors reference
>   items in different view hierarchies? That's illegal.'

This is my code in the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = newTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCellTableViewCell
    let tableTextView = UITextView()
    tableTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    cell.addSubview(tableTextView)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should call:

```
cell.addSubview(tableTextView)
```

and then attach the constraints, moreover:

> All constraints must involve only views that are within scope of the
>   receiving view. Specifically, any views involved must be either the
>   receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view.

So your code might be:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = newTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCellTableViewCell
    let tableTextView = UITextView()
    cell.addSubView(tableTextView)
    tableTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    tableTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. This comment is fixed my problem :)

Comment: This seems very wrong, it should be `cell.addSubview(tableTextView)` , preferably `cell.contentView`. You don't want to add the cell to a text view.

Comment: @Sulthan It's evidently a typo error from OP, I fixed the question

Answer (score 0):

The subview must be added to the superview before the constraints are applied:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = newTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewCell", for: indexPath) as! NewCellTableViewCell
    let tableTextView = UITextView()
    tableTextView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cell.addSubView(tableTextView)
    tableTextView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    tableTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. This comment is fixed my problem :)

Comment: Actually the `UITextView` seems to be added as the sub view of `cell`. Not the other way around.